# SignalR cannot connect to remote server

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I have a SignalR project in winform.
When I start the server, the application starts the server at the address I specified. For example: "http: // localhost: 4951"
In the client, I specify the IP address of my computer as "http: //192.169.1.101:8080/signalr". However, the client cannot connect to the remote computer on which the server application is running, and it catches exception 400 (invalid request). If I run the client application locally where the server is running, everything is fine.
[Server start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyexi.png)
[Client code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6MjH.png)

**Server**

```
    try
        {
            _signalR = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:4951/");

            writeToLog("Server started at:http://localhost:4951/");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message + " " + exception.InnerException);
        }
```

**Startup**

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr",new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableJSONP = true,
            EnableJavaScriptProxies = false,
            EnableDetailedErrors = true
        });
    }
```

**Client**

```
    private async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        _signalRConnection = new HubConnection("http://192.168.1.105:4951/signalr");
        _signalRConnection.StateChanged += _signalRConnection_StateChanged;

        _hubProxy = _signalRConnection.CreateHubProxy("CommunicationHub");

        _hubProxy.On<string, string>("AddMessage", (name, message) => writeToLog($"{name}:{message}"));

        btnConnect.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            await _signalRConnection.Start();

            await _hubProxy.Invoke("RegisterClient", "T001");

            btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writeToLog($"Error:{ex.Message}");
            btnConnect.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    private void _signalRConnection_StateChanged(StateChange obj)
    {
        if (obj.NewState == ConnectionState.Connected)
            writeToLog("Connected");
        else if (obj.NewState == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
            writeToLog("Disconnected");
    }
```

**Exception when Client try connect to remote server**

```
Disconnected
Error:StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, 
Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 28 Jan 2020 05:52:24 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Content-Length: 334
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
}
```

Comment: Post the code and the full exception *texts* in the message itself. Images can't be compiled or googled

Comment: As the server listens at localhost, your client can only connect to localhost, not that IP address. Basic Windows TCP/IP mandate.

Comment: Also the port numbers are different

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i edit my question. There is I added my code